Question about Unbiasedness of Raw Sample Moments, Odd Simulation Results
I'm performing a Monte Carlo simulation to confirm that $$m_k'=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^k$$ is an unbiased estimator for $\text{E}[X^k]$. In the event $X\overset{iid}{\sim} \chi_1^2$, we have $\text{E}[X^k] = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1+2j)$ (source). To verify the unbiasedness of $m_k'$, I perform the following simulation:
library(tidyverse)

kth_sample_raw_moment <- function(x, k){
  return(mean(x^k))
}

kth_raw_moment <- function(k, df){
  return(prod(df + 0:(k-1)*2))
}

draw_sample_moment <- function(df, n, k, i){
  set.seed(i)
  x <- rchisq(n, df = df)
  output <- tibble(
    estimate = kth_sample_raw_moment(x, k),
    kth_moment = k,
    df = df,
    sample_size = n,
    true_value = kth_raw_moment(k, df),
    iter_num = i,
  )
  return(output)
}

draw_N_sample_moments <- function(N, df, n, k){
  output <- 1:N %>% 
    map_df(\(i) draw_sample_moment(df, n, k, i))
  return(output)
}

bias_of_estimator <- function(N, df, n, k){
  output <- draw_N_sample_moments(N, df, n, k) %>% 
    summarize(
      bias = mean(estimate - true_value),
      var_est = var(estimate)
    ) %>% 
    mutate(
      df = df,
      kth_moment = k, 
      sample_size = n,
      iterations = N
    )
  return(output)
}

results <- map_df(1:10, \(k) bias_of_estimator(N = 1e4, 1, n = 1e3, k))

As $k$ increases, the magnitude of the empirical bias begins to balloon.



Kth moment
Empirical Bias
Empirical Variance




1
0.0004955682
2.047726e-03


2
-0.0002376841
9.775483e-02


3
-0.0208033800
1.005684e+01


4
-0.3669142243
1.902190e+03


5
-6.8067172462
5.670055e+05


6
-145.6305751734
2.343917e+08


7
-3520.6126356374
1.214408e+11


8
-93062.0716106473
7.307064e+13


9
-2627288.7106844918
4.840854e+16


10
-78133410.5134635270
3.410351e+19



What's happening here? My hunch is that as variance of $m_k'$ increases, the sample size (iterations N) required for the empirical bias to be a sufficiently good estimate of the true bias increases (i.e the rate of convergence associated with the LLN depends on the variance of the underlying random variables). This shouldn't result in the empirical bias being monotonic in $k$ though, so I'm not sure why this is happening (if not by sheer chance). Many thanks for any advice!

Consider computing the actual variances of your estimates, rather than the empirical variances.  The calculation is simple and uses information you already have.  Then, compute the standard errors of your estimates and compare your bias estimates to those SEs.  Only then will you have a legitimate basis to determine what is really happening.

The variances get to be enormous, meaning that there is tremendous imprecision in estimation (this is not surprising for estimating high-order moments). The bias seems to be well within two standard deviations of zero.
Yes, this is kind of tantamount to seeing a hypothesis test not reject and declaring that there must not be an effect, but if you see your results as strong evidence that something is amiss in your calculations, the evidence is less compelling than you think.
Something that may interest you is to run the experiment several times with several different seeds, perhaps 50 times or whatever you have the patience to let run on your computer. Then check out what the empirical biases are. Do they jump around a bunch but cancel out to be about zero? What happens if you run it 500 or 5000 times instead of 50?

The hypothesis test analogy is amazing! After trying this for a few different seeds it does in fact jump around so the initial pattern was in fact mere chance.
